# Как в плагине для webpack UglifyJsPlugin исключить конкретные файлы для оптимизации?

Tags: webpack

Файлы с кодом angular (например, app.js) при оптимизации ломаются, что делать? без оптимизации файл core.js весит 3.8 мб, с оптимизацией 256кб

```js
'use strict';

let app = angular.module("myApp", []).run(function($rootScope, $http){
    alert(1)
});
```

```html
'use strict';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/build', // точка входа в приложение

  entry: { // точки входа
    core: './js/core',
    app: './js/app',
  },

  output: { // выхоные файлы
    path: __dirname + "/public/js/",
    publicPath: '/public/js/',
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: '[name]'
  },

  watch: NODE_ENV == 'development', // прослушиваем изменения
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },

  devtool: NODE_ENV == 'development' ? 'cheap-inline-module-source-map' : null, // дебаг

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // отключение сборки, если возникла ошибка


   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery"
   }),
 

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
      LANG: JSON.stringify('ru')
    })
  ],

  module: {

    loaders: [{ // используем ES6 to ES5
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }]

  }

};

if (NODE_ENV == 'development') {

  module.exports.plugins.push( // оптимизация файлов JS
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console:true,
        unsafe: true
      }
    })

  )

}
```

Comment: все дело в вашем коде приложения, почитайте про angular strict di.  Все нужно переписывать там где вы внедряете зависимости

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог этот к кусок кода в моем случае.
Он исключает опредленные модули.

You can specify all variables that should not be mangled.
For example if your vendor dependency doesn't use modules and relies on global variables. Most of angular modules relies on angular global variable, so we should keep it unchanged

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: {
      except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require', 'angular']
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить аннотации в ангуляр код. Для автоматической подстановки аннотаций есть даже плагин для bable https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate.

```
let app = angular.module("myApp", []).run(['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http){
    alert(1)
}]);
```

После добавления аннотаций код будет минифицироваться корректно.